# Prevent laravel session from being cleared when setInterval() is called

Tags: laravel

I have a javascript function that reloads a page every 1 seconds but whenever i try doing this on other page.

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success','anything');
```

If i receive it on my blade file as

```
{{$success}}
```

the data for success is null because the javascript setInterval() whiich is running on all pages every 1s has reset the laravel session. If the setInterval method is commented it works perfectly. How do i fix this.

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of flashing data for the next request, but you can look into reflashing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data

Comment: What exactly happens every second and why?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `back()` method return a `response` with a 301 code, that is a redirect HTTP code... that `with()` method doesn't is useless, because will be destroyed after the script ends.
In other words, image that `with` method as a PHP declaration just before the return, so something like this

```
$success = 'anything';
return ...;
```

If you are returning a view for example, with this change, it will looks like this (let's say that the view is `something {{$success}} something`):

```
$success = 'anything';
$your_view = "something". e($success) ."something";
return $your_view;
```

This will return a 200 code and that string as content, but a 301 body, and so the body of the `redirect()->back()` will be ignored, because it's a redirect code, and just after the `return redirect()->back()` all the variables will be destroyed, and so also the `$success` element.
Chronologically the things will happen in this order

1. JS send a request
2. PHP script is been fired
3. the `$success` variable is been created and assigned to it `'anything'`
4. is fired the `redirect()->back()` method, and passed to it `$success`
5. Laravel builds the 301 response and the `$success` is not been used
6. the script returns the 301 response and so all the variables of the script are been destroyed (deallocated), including `$success`
7. the browser receive the 301 and so it send a request to the address that is inside the 301 response
8. PHP is been fired
9. Laravel do what it has to do to that response, but keep attention that the `$success` doesn't exist here, because is part of another script, so here, at the moment, it doesn't exist any more.
   So you have to find a way to move information between two script associated to the sam SESSION run in two different moments... and what other way if not using the Session?
   In fact Laravel ships with a lot of method that can be used to manage the Session, including `Session::flash(key, value)`, which will destroy the value after the end of the next script, and so at the end of the script that Laravel fires after the redirect.

So what you have to do is, firstly flash the data in the session

```
use Session;
...

Session::flash('success','anything');
return redirect()->back();
```

And then in the view that you aspect to be reloaded, add the message if the session has something associated to the key you are using, and so the `'success'` key:

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
     {{session()->get('success')}}
@endif
```

And that's it

Comment: same issue  happens when i use the realrashid laravel sweetalert

Comment: It’s the same motivation, in the controller that is fired after the refresh (the one without the return redirect()...) you have to check if session has “success” and if yes, add the sweetalert